# How to know the visibility of a symbol in an object file

Tags: c++, c, unix, nm

The visibility (from __ attribute __(visibility("...")) and -fvisibility) of a symbol can be known from a so file

```
nm -C lib.so
```

t is hidden, T is exported(i.e. default). But how to get this information from an object file directly?

```
nm -C lib.o
```

Will always print T for non C-static symbols whatever the visibility is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility is different from whether the symbol is local or global (which is what the lower-case/upper-case letters describe). A hidden symbol still can have external linkage, i.e. it is not limited to a translation unit.

I don't think `nm` has an option to show visibility, but you can use either

```
objdump -Ct lib.o
```

which will show an attribute `.hidden` if the symbol is hidden or

```
readelf -s lib.o
```

which has a column for the visibility (`DEFAULT`/`HIDDEN`).

Answer (score 0):

I think `visibility` is a concept for shared library, not for object file.

The following is a test to verify it.

```
//math.cpp
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int bbbb;
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) int aaaa;
```

- If we compile it to a object file, the two symbol are global(the `S` is upper case to indicate that it is global)

```
> g++ -c math.c
> nm math.o
000000000000007c S _aaaa
0000000000000078 S _bbbb
```

- If we compile it to a shared library, we will see the hidden symbol(`aaaa`) is marker as local.

```
> g++ -shared -fPIC -o libmath.so math.cpp
> nm libmath.so
0000000000004004 s _aaaa
0000000000004000 S _bbbb
```

Comment: You build a shared library from object files, therefore visibility information must come from object files, therefore it is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on Apple platforms, and `objdump` can't recognize your object file (`file format not recognized`), It may due to the object file is actually bitcode file.

You can try `llvm-nm`, which supports more formats including bitcode files:

```
llvm-nm main.o
```

or

```
xcrun llvm-nm main.o
```

if you have Xcode installed.